# Excel: Copy the same locked ($) cell value, from multiple excel books, which name grow incrementally (+1)

Tags: excel

I am building an Excel tool to compare different Business cases.

The Business cases are build in the same template, so I can get the same data, from across multiple business cases and compare it. No issue there.

But, I need 34 cells of info from 1 business case, and the same info from up to 100 business cases – in 1 sheet. So I want to automate the formular of retrieving data, from across the business cases.

The cell value formula looks like this: ='[Business Case (1).xlsx]Summary'!$D$4

This returns with the value I need, but when I drag copy it to the cell below, it (logically) still returns with: ='[Business Case (1).xlsx]Summary'!$D$4

So the question is, how do I automate the formular, so I can keep the cell value locked, but the excel book number growing with 1.
e.g.

- ='[Business Case (**1**).xlsx]Summary'!$D$4
- ='[Business Case (**2**).xlsx]Summary'!$D$4
- ='[Business Case (**3**).xlsx]Summary'!$D$4
- ='[Business Case (**4**).xlsx]Summary'!$D$4

Without having to manually change the name, for 34 cells, pr. Line, for my 100 lines.

Best Regards
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference a workbook or worksheet using the INDIRECT function, so you could put the name of the workbooks in a separate column (Business Case (1), Business Case (2) etc.) and reference them using [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261):

```
=INDIRECT("'["&workbook&"]"&sheet&"'!"&ref)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Duo :)

I have tried this: =INDIREKTE("='["&B2&" "&C2&""&D2&"]"&E2&"'!"&F2)

But it just bounces me to "#REFERENCE!"

B2 is the file name = Business case, C2 the number =(1), D2 the format  =.xlsx, E2 the function = Summary, and F2 the cell value looking to retrieve = $D4$

Comment: Sorry, not what to do, "Where to look" = Summary (Its a sheet name)

Answer (score 0):

After following Duodenalsalmons advice, I Finally got it working =)!

It required a bit more wigelling with the formula, but I got i working in the end.

Comment: Glad it worked out - maybe add this as a comment, and mark the answer as the official answer (or edit it if my version was missing something crucial!)